# Replace repeating characters with exceptions

Tags: php, regex, replace

How can you translate this into Regex: Replace any char (aka '.') that is repeating more than once and replace it with one of that char with the exception of "ii" and "iii".

```
$reg = preg_replace('/(.)/1{1,}/','', $string);
```

Now this must replace `VVVVV` with `V` or `....` with `.` and must not replace `Criiid` (or `Criid`) but `Criiiiiiid` with `Crid`.

Feel free to comment if you don't understand the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/([^i])\1+|(i){4,}/', '\1\2', $string)
```

Note that this will squeeze *everything* -- spaces, newlines, etc.

Comment: I believe in PHP's PCRE you can use the branch reset group `(?|...|...)`, so that it becomes `preg_replace('/(?|([^i])\1+|(i){4,})/', '\1', $string)`

Comment: @ExplosionPills what exactly do you mean by `squeeze`

Comment: @ExplosionPills can you also tell me the `|` which you have used is between `\1+` and `i{4,}` or `([^i])\1+` and `(i){4,}`

Comment: @aelor `|` is the second thing.  Squeeze just means translating repetitions of a character to a single version of that character (think of squeezing in real life)

Comment: @ExplosionPills so you can even do `([^i])\1+|(i)\1{4,}`

Comment: @aelor no because this would squeeze `iiii`

Comment: ohk got it this is the right one `([^i])\1+|(i)\2{3,}` thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first alternative replaces anything but `i`, the second alternative replaces any `i`s which occur four times or more:

```
$reg = preg_replace('/([^i])\1{1,}|(i){4,}/','\1\2', $string);
```

Or (thanks to @Enissay):

```
$reg = preg_replace('/([^i])\1+|(i){4,}/','\1\2', $string);
```

Comment: @Enissay: Thanks :) I just copied the first part from the question so it looks familiar to the poster :)